# Is there a way to allow a function to accept definite number of arguments in js

Tags: javascript

I need to limit the argument of the functions in my js.Is there any way to set the function arguments limitation while invoking.

Comment: What should happen if you pass more…?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

**No.** You can never *really* limit the accepted number of arguments. Any function will simply run with any amount of arguments.

You can however create a higher order function that wraps a function in order to control the number of arguments the wrapped function *receives*:

```
function limitArgs(maxArgs, fn) {
    return function(...allArgs) {
        const limitedArgs = allArgs.slice(0, maxArgs);
        return fn(...limitedArgs);
    };
}
```

When this function `limitArgs` is invoked the following happens:

- Takes a number `maxArgs`, that defines how many arguments the wrapped function must receive at most.
- Takes a function `fn`, which is the function to limit the arguments for.
- Returns a function that, when called, creates an array of the first <`maxArgs`> arguments that the function was given. It will then call `fn` spreading only the created arguments array.

**Working example:**

```js
// As arrow function oneliner this time:
const limitArgs = (maxArgs, fn) => (...allArgs) => fn(...allArgs.slice(0, maxArgs));

const testFn = (...args) => console.log(`Arguments given: [${args}]`);

const testFn4 = limitArgs(4, testFn);
testFn4(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
// Expected output: 'Arguments given: [1,2,3,4]'

const testFn2 = limitArgs(2, testFn);
testFn2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
// Expected output: 'Arguments given: [1,2]'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to allow a function to accept definite number of arguments in js

No, you can't.  However, there is a limitation of the amount of arguments and it's implementation dependent (browsers, backend tech, Etc,.).

An alternative is checking the length of the implicit `arguments` array within a function (non arrow-functions).

**For example:**

*I'm assuming you want to throw an Error*

```js
function fn(a, b, c) {
  if(arguments.length > 3) throw new Error('Too many arguments!');
  
  console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
}

fn('Ele', 'from', 'SO'); // Will work!
fn('Ele', 'from', 'SO', 'Hello!'); // Won't work!
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another function as a "middleware function"

```
function invoker(func, ...args) { 
   if (args.length > 4) throw new Error('Too many arguments!'); 
   else if (typeof(func) === "function") func.apply(null,args) 
}
function foo (...args) {
   console.log(args.length)
}
```

Run `invoker(foo, 1,2,3,4,5)` will throw an error. 
Run `invoker(foo, 1,2,3,4)` will run `foo(1,2,3,4)`